# How to set timout for download.file in R

Tags: r, reporting-services, timeout

I'm using R to download sql server reports that take 5-10 minutes to generate. I tried to change the timeout option but it still times out in about a minute. Any suggestions?

```
options(timeout=1000)
download.file(ssrsUrl, filePath, mode="wb")
```